# irreducible polynomials over GF(q)

Tags: abstract-algebra, irreducible-polynomials, quadratic-residues

Assuming $q$  is a power of an odd prime $p$ I would like to find a necessary and sufficient condition on $a,b$ such that $P(x)=x^2 +ax+b$ is irreducible
over $\mathbb F_q$.

I thought about enforcing the discriminant of $P(x)$ to be quadratic non residue, however is it really necessary and sufficient in finite fields?.

TNX in advance.

Comment: Yes, it is...and in fact the only condition that remains for all primes.BTW, your $\;F\;$ should be $\;GF(p)\;$ or $\;\Bbb F_p\;$, right?

Comment: Or maybe the field of $p^r$ elements, since OP refers to "a power of an odd prime".

Comment: The factorization $x^2-d = (x-\sqrt{d})(x+\sqrt{d})$ stays true in $\mathbf{F}_q$, except that $\sqrt{-1} = 2$ and $\sqrt{5} = 0$ in $\mathbf{F}_5$. With this in mind, $x^2-d$ is irreducible over $\mathbf{F}_q$ iff $\mathbf{F}_q(\sqrt{d}) = \mathbf{F}_{q^2}$ iff $\sqrt{d} \not \in \mathbf{F}_q$ iff $d$ is not a square in $ \mathbf{F}_q$

Comment: Edited: the usual style is that $q$ is a power of an odd prime $p$. People will find it easier to read, I think.